# How to maintain ssd cache with dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install ubuntu on windows 8 with intel smart response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234371/install-ubuntu-on-windows-8-with-intel-smart-response)

I have a Samsung Series 7 Chronos laptop. It has an 8GB SSD Cached to a 1TB hard drive using some Intel caching utility to enable a fast boot. Furthermore, it has Windows 8 installed on it.

My question is how can I dual-boot with Ubuntu and not mess up the SSD cache that that is set up in Windows 8.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for the cache feature in Linux.

Comment: It appears you're wrong to state it's not supported. See [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020155) on the Ubuntu forums for a solution with `dm_raid`.

Comment: @gertvdijk, no, dmraid does not support the cache feature.