# how can I install ubuntu on dell inspirion 15z

Tags: boot, hard-drive, uefi, dell

I am trying to install ubuntu 14 on a dell inspirion 15z with intel chip.  The machine came preloaded with windows 8.  I want to wipe windows out and run only ubuntu.  When I try to install the installer does not detect any discs.  I have modified the SATA in the bios from ata to ahci and intel smart response technology.  Secure boot is off.  Ubuntu crashes on install. ProcEnviron  [errno13] permission denied.  I have tried legacy mode and uefi and still no discs are detected.  I also tried to install fedora and mint and they both stopped at the same place--no discs detected?  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: When you say that "the installer does not detect any discs," do you mean that the disk devices are not detected at all (that is, there's no `/dev/sda` to which you can install), that the disk is present but appears to be empty, or that there's no "install alongside" option? These are three very different symptoms with three very different causes and possible sets of solutions. Also, you say "Ubuntu crashes on install," which implies you got past that initial hurdle. You *must* be more precise about what's happening!

Comment: Thanks for helping me ask better questions.  Probably a screenshot would be more helpful.  Fedora flat out said no hard drive was detected.  The ubuntu partition window was completely blank.  Pressing + or - or change (I believe those were the choices) caused the install program to crash at that point.  I posted an answer linking back to a previous question that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Install ubuntu on windows 8 with intel smart response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234371/install-ubuntu-on-windows-8-with-intel-smart-response)

For anyone else having this problem this was the final step that made the installation work.  I had to find the intel gui and disable the acceleration.  The installation still did not recognize that I had an OS installed, but it could find my hard drive and everything worked fine after that, because I didn't care about preserving the windows 8 install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this with my Vaio ! Ubuntu have 2 distro 32 and 64 that 64 is for `UEFI` boot ! but if you want to remove windows first i propose you have a backup ! then when u want to install linux in firstly menu select install linux instead of windows ! do you try this ?
if not try this an remember that you can make >=200 MB drive for boot and set boot drive on this drive not all of hard disc ! and also you can use all of hard for boot ....try this 2 choice too !

Answer (score -2):

Don't make it harder than it is. Just wipe your hard drive first,then reformat it, then you should be able to install Ubuntu, provided your hardware is not creating the problem. Remember to save(backup) your important files first!
P.S.  I read that Windows 8 has some new programming that doesn't play well with Linux.

Comment: He's not 'Making it any harder than it is'. Your answer does not provide any information and is even derogatory. Please consider editing to improve it.