# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.10 on the integrated SSD of an Asus UX32A

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

As the title suggests, I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on the 24GB integrated SSD of an Asus UX32A. I took into consideration this answer - [How to boot Ubuntu from SSD drive which cannot be selected as boot device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234111/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-ssd-drive-which-cannot-be-selected-as-boot-device) - and basically these are the steps that I followed:

1. Deleted the info from the SSD
2. Converted the SSD to MBR
3. Created a small partition for `/boot` on the main HDD (~200 MB)
4. Selected from BIOS the SSD as the primary boot partition
5. When the installation began, I created on the SSD a partition for `/` and one for `swap`
6. Although the SSD theoretically was MBR, it complained about not having a BIOS Boot Partition, so I also created one for the bios-grub.

Everything worked fine, except for the fact that after the restart, the system did not recognize the SSD anymore and I was unable to select it as the main boot device. Furthermore, if I use `diskpart`, it shows that the SSD is GPT, and not MBR, although I initially converted it to MBR.

Do you have any idea on how could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try examining your firmware boot options. Look for options to enable CSM, BIOS, or legacy boot features; or to disable EFI or UEFI boot features.
2. Launch Linux's fdisk (*not* gdisk, parted, or GParted) and use the `a` option to set the "bootable flag" on the one partition that you should see. Use the `w` option to save changes.
3. If neither of the above works, consult [this page of mine,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) which goes into more detail about this problem and provides more obscure possible workarounds.