# Im New To Ubuntu And Need A Quick Help

Tags: installation, partitioning

I have 1 24gb ssd and a 750gb regular drive, and when I install ubuntu to my SSD then my other drive is separate. I would like to install ubuntu so that my computer recognises both my ssd and regular drive the same, is there any way to do this when installing ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please any help is appreciated, I simply am looking to just merge the two drives together without any 3rd party program at set-up, if possible.

Comment: I found some great resources from ItsFOSS who list some great books for Ubuntu Beginners at http://itsfoss.com/5-free-ubuntu-books-for-beginners/ The Ubuntu manual covers a lot of the questions about partitioning with good explanations of working with various systems

Comment: The drives are separate. It's just that in Windows an Intel Smart Response driver uses the ssd for caching. See http://askubuntu.com/q/252140/88802 for how to do that in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "merge the two drives together"? Do you want to have one "virtual" partition on two physical discs? Then probably you should google LVM (I've never used it, so it's all I can say).

But why do you want to merge the two discs? If I were you, I would use the fast SSD for some selected data (for fast boot or whatever) and HDD for the rest. When they are merged together you can't control where your data is stored and you don't benefit from having fast SSD (unless you are very lucky).

If the reason for merging is that you don't like too many logical partitions in your computer then you don't have to worry: in linux you don't normally navigate with drives but with a virtual directory structure (see the next paragraph). So some smart *mounting* may be a solution: you can mount your SSD in some **folder** (e.g. inside another folder stored physically on HDD!) (or even divide it into partitions and mount in several folders).

Finally: if - as you said - you're installing ubuntu on SSD, then you can just use the standard schema: put your ubuntu ("/" directory called root) on SDD (24 GB *should* suffice since my old installation is 16 GB) and your home folder ("/home") on HDD. All your personal data will be stored in one place (home) and you will benefit from having system files on a fast SSD  (dunno if it is the best way of utilising SSD, but for sure it is the simplest).

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to present the drives the same as in Windows where the sad is used for caching (transparent). Anyway still +1 for the alternative approach I would use as well. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/234121/88802