# Cannot boot Ubuntu from SSD in ASUS K55VD

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, asus, ssd

As the title would suggest, I am having trouble booting from my new SSD that I installed in my ASUS R500V K55VD today.  I have been running Ubuntu on the HDD since I got the laptop, but I wanted to upgrade to an SSD.  I installed the SSD in a caddy that slots in to where the DVD drive was.

When entering the BIOS I can see that SATA is in AHCI mode and that my SSD and HDD are both being discovered, however I cannot see a boot option for the SSD; only the HDD has an option.  I cannot see a way to add my SSD to the boot list.

Booting in to the Ubuntu 13.04 live USB I can see that the OS installed itself on my SSD, but I simply cannot get the BIOS to boot from it.  Has anyone else had any problems using two storage devices on this laptop that can shed any light on this?

I also tried using the suggestions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234111/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-ssd-drive-which-cannot-be-selected-as-boot-device) question, but I still end up at the grub rescue prompt :(  I have the following layout:

HDD (sda):

- 512MB /boot
- rest /media/data

SSD (sdb):

- All /

I have tried installing the bootloader in the /boot partition and just directly in sda with no observable difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question since this problem is now solved.

I managed to solve my problem by formatting both drives and creating new partition tables as the problem was the GPT. Creating the /boot partition on the HDD and placing / on the SSD solved my problems as per the linked question.